# "tf get" from command line doesn't get latest, UI does

Tags: version-control, tfs, cmd

Did I get the syntax correct?

```
  tf get .\Web\project.root /recursive
  All files are up to date.


  tf get /version:T .\Web\project.root /recursive
  All files are up to date.
```

Getting latest using the command line will report that all files are up to date when they are not!  However, when I get latest using the TFS UI within Visual Studio, the latest code does actually download.

Until this gets resolves, my super fancy msbuild script can't be used without opening visual studio to get latest first!!

```
  <Target Name="GetLatestCoreLibraries" Condition="'$(GetLatest)' == 'true'">
    <Exec Command='tf get /version:T "$(CoreLibPath)\Source\Libraries /recursive' ContinueOnError="false" />
  </Target>
```

The $(CoreLibPath) is a relative path passed into the script.  Something like...

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CoreLibraryPath>..\..\Core\Release\xx.xx.xx.xx</CoreLibraryPath>
  </PropertyGroup
```

Is using relative paths to the local file system less reliable than using SCS paths?  ie... $/Core/Release/xx.xx.xx.xx/Source/Libraries"?

Could it be that we're sometimes using Dev Studio UI, and other times using the command line that is confusing the command line version of TFS?

Comment: Your syntax is correct, assuming the itemspec is correct.  What folder are you clicking on in the UI to get latest?  Can you simply use that itemspec in the CLC?  Eg, `tf get $/... /recursive`.  Worst case, you can get latest for your entire workspace (not the entire server, just what you have mapped) by using `tf get $/ /recursive`.

Comment: hi edward, i've updated my question based on your comment.  i think what you are recommending is to drop the local path for the itemspec in favor of the source control path names.

Comment: No, using local paths is not any less reliable than server paths.  Is this part of an MSBuild script?  Are you invoking it as part of TFS Build?  Is $(CoreLibPath) in your workspace mappings for your build definition already?

Comment: This is being used from an msbuild script, but isn't part of a TFS Build yet.  The $(CoreLibPath) is defined in a separate file used for cross project file linking and is imported into my build script to locate the core libraries that are contained on a separate team project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I realized my mistake.  It was very simple.

```
Command = 

    'tf get
       /version:T 
       /recursive
       "$(CoreLibPath)\Source\Libraries <<<-- Missing closing quote.
     '
```

When you miss the closing double quote on a *tf get*, there is no error thrown.  It simply reports that "All files are up to date."

```
c:\Web\Release\x.x\x.x.xxxx>tf get /version:T "..\..\..\..\..\Core\Release\x.x\x.x.xxxx.xxxxx(xxxx xx xx - xxx)\Source\Libraries /recursive
All files are up to date.
```

> Q: *Is using relative paths to the local file system less reliable than using SCS paths? ie... $/Core/Release/xx.xx.xx.xx/Source/Libraries"?*

A: No, it doesn't seem to be any less reliable.

> Q: *Could it be that we're sometimes using Dev Studio UI, and other times using the command line that is confusing the command line version of TFS?*

A: No, this was a case of user confusion, not SCS confusion.

Comment: So it was mismatched. You just didn't have a path ""$(CoreLibPath)\Source\Libraries /recursive' ContinueOnError="false"". :)


In all seriousness, good catch.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `/force` parameter.  That'll force everything to be retrieved, which maybe you don't want.

Alternatively you could get the [MSBuild Extension Pack](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/) from CodePlex - they have MSBuild tasks  that wrap these calls and work with IntelliSense if you're using Visual Studio to manage your build scripts.

Your `itemspec` looks odd to me, but I don't have any specific corrections to offer.  I explicitly call out the workspace when using command line calls, e.g. `tf get "$/<our product>/<branch>[/<project>]" /force /recursive`.  Otherwise pathing is relative to the current active workspace mapping.

Comment: i'm using the relative local path and files names.  please see the updates in the question.

Comment: If you're mixing validating the `get` with UI calls and testing your command-line calls, the command-line calls might indeed report 'all files up to date' without the `force` parameter.  The UI offers opportunities to override behavior that you have to explicitly specify on the command line.

Comment: You may be right... I hate to think the only solution to this problem is to use the /all or /force flags, since it will add so much time to the build, and also overwrite tweaks developers have snuck into their own web and app config files.

Comment: @antwarpes: if you're mixing doing gets from the UI and from the command-line, what makes you think you're not *actually* up-to-date?

Comment: @EdwardThomson: from the command line i would attempt to get latest, and it would erroneously report that all files were up to date.  i would then fire up developer studio and use the team explorer UI to do the same thing, and the updated source files would actually download.

Comment: @antwarpes, are you sure you're getting the same workspace/local pathing between the VS environment and your command-line execution?  i.e. you don't have something like Debug & Release paths under the same parent folder and the two environments are working in different physical locations.  If you delete the local project files completely and run the command line `get`, do you get the results you expect?

Comment: @DaveE, I switched my paths to the server scs paths and everything seems to work.  my current dir was c:/Web/Release/x.x/x.x.x/>

`tf get /version:T .\Web\Libraries /recursive` to
`tf get /version:T $/Web/Release/x.x/x.x.x/Web /recursive`

So, there does seem to be a disconnect with the local mappings vs server mappings.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is that the user does not have access to the project collection. In my case I could somehow see the directories but did not have access to pull down the code. I had to have a TFS admin add me as "developer" access.